# SQL Server Agent logs in as guest on a linked server

Tags: security, sql-server-agent

I have a job called @test_credentials which runs the following query

```
select * from openquery(SERVER2, 
'select USER_NAME(),* from openquery(SERVER1,''SELECT USER_NAME() '')')
```

and outputs those results to a file.

> Job '@test_credentials' : Step 1, 'test_credentials' : Began Executing 2015-08-31 17:53:45
>
> guest                                                                                                                            LinkedServerUser
>
> (1 rows(s) affected)

1. The linked server definitions for both `SERVER1` and `SERVER2` are using
   the linkedserveruser to login to one another (security context option).
2. Both linked server definitions are defined with the same options
3. The linkedserveruser user account exists on both servers and is not disabled in anyway.
4. The service account running the AGENT is identical for both `SERVER1`
   and `SERVER2`.

So my question is this:

Why is SQL Server Agent logging in as guest on SERVER2 when executing this job?

Comment: Are the job owners same ?  You may find [SQL Server Agent jobs and user contexts](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/tibor_karaszi/archive/2009/09/19/sql-server-agent-jobs-and-user-contexts.aspx). Also, sysinternals has `whoami.exe` that you can play around to debug your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally [I would try using ORIGINAL_LOGIN() instead of USER_NAME().](http://sqlstudies.com/2015/06/24/which-user-function-do-i-use/)  USER_NAME() returns the **database principal** or user associated with your login in the database you are connecting to.  In this case you are probably connecting to `master` in both cases.  If LinkedServerUser doesn't have a specific login in `master` on `SERVER2` then you will see `GUEST`.

If on the other hand you use `ORIGINAL_LOGIN()` you will get the **server principal** that connected, which will probably be LinkedServerUser in both cases.

Comment: Hi Kenneth, that worked thanks. I'm still having an issue though with a Job that is using this same linked server setup. The investigation continues.

Comment: Does this look familiar? "NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON"?  If so you have a double hop issue.  It's caused when you go from one computer to another and then that machine goes to another.  Unless Kerberos authentication is set up correctly between the machines you will get that error.

Comment: Hi Kenneth, thanks for that. Turns out there was yet another sp nested inside the second one that was being executed on an entirely different machine, different environment. Anyway, it took reading every line of SQL code to find it.